# Generate false candidates from Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a CSV file that contains the following columns:

1. Id: Unique Identifier
2. label: Label for a given word
3. def1: first definition of the word
4. def2: second definition of the word
5. match: True for matching definitions

```
    Id    label    def1                        def2                                         match
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    a1    Apple    fruit of the apple tree     Editable fruit produced by the apple tree       1
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    a2    Apple    American Technology company  Apple inc. American company                    1 
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    a3    Apple    Music online service         Music and video streaming service              1
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

is there a simple way to mix the generate the wrong pair of definitions for each record between the items that have the same label such that each entry could have the correct definitions with match=1, and wrong definitions with match =0:

```
Id    label    def1                        def2                                         match
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
a1    Apple    Fruit of the apple tree       Editable fruit produced by the apple tree      1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
a1    Apple    Apple inc. American company   Fruit of the apple tree                        0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
a2    Apple    American Technology company   Apple inc. American company                    1 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
a2    Apple    American Technology company   Editable fruit produced by the apple tree      0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
a3    Apple    Music online service          Music and video streaming service              1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
a3    Apple    Music online service          Apple inc. American company                    0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

To do so, I used the permutation to generate all possible candidates:

```
# import pandas as pd
import pandas as pd

# creating data frame
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['q54', 'apple', 'fruit apple', 'fruit'],
                        ['q55', 'apple', 'inc', 'apple inc'], ],
                columns=['QId', 'label', 'wikidata', 'wikiedia'])

print(df)


# importing product
from itertools import product

# apply product method
#print(list(product(df['wikidata'], df['wikiedia'])))
data =list(product(df['wikidata'], df['wikiedia']))

for tpl in  list(product(df['wikidata'], df['wikiedia'])): 
  print(tpl)
```

This code produces the following output:

```
('fruit apple', 'fruit')
('fruit apple', 'apple inc')
('inc', 'fruit')
('inc', 'apple inc')
```

where the entities that have the same row index are True, others are False,
in our case ('fruit apple', 'fruit') and ('inc', 'apple inc') are True, the rest are false.
But How can I make use of the output to make the whole false entries as illustrated in the second dataframe?

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do and what you have tried so far

Comment: I explained it in more details with code

Comment: Sorry. Still do not understand. When is the match True and when is it False?

Comment: I am sorry for that, but in the first data frame the entities do match, they have the same definition, but I need to generate a non-match pair for each matching row, by mixing the def2 of each row with another row. It is something like generating permutations. The output should be something like the second data frame, correct pair of detentions labeled 1, and the wrong pair labeled 0